# Django date time query returns None

Tags: python, django

My Model is as follows:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
from django.db import models



class user_table(models.Model):
    #The Facebook unique user ID
    facebook_UUID=models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    #Apple Push Notification token updated by, the logIn API.
    #APNS is deleted after if the user logs out.
    apns_token=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_seen_lat=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_seen_lon=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #A dump of the last Facebook "Me" JSON Object {first_name, last_name, bio, birthday, gender,
    #  picture.heaight(400).width(400)}
    facebook_details_json=JSONField()
    #Date of last web service request by this user. Used for computing last seen.


    last_request_datetime=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    #A boolean indicating if the user is logged in, or the user has logged out. This
    #boolean is initiated as true. It is only set to false when the user explicitly logs out
    #utilizing the sign out API
    is_logged_in=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When I query the last_request_datetime, I will get None:

IN[0]

```
user_table.objects.get(pk=1).__dict__
```

OUT[0]

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x53b7930>,
 'apns_token': u'Token123',
 'facebook_UUID': u'Lozan',
 'facebook_details_json': {u'facebook': u'Lozan'},
 'id': 1,
 'is_logged_in': True,
 'last_request_datetime': None,
 'last_seen_lat': u'12.12',
 'last_seen_lon': u'12.12'}
```

I used dummies for all the other fields obviously. I tried changing the field name, but that was not it. I am using SQLite. I tried in both jupyter and the terminal. When I look at the database in PyCharm though, I can see the epoch entry there. So the creation does work. The Field type is TEXT in PyCharm database explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:
    There is a default value when I initiate the datetime field, which is in epoch like format. When I update that field once, then it works perfectly, both in the database explorer in PyCharm and in the consoles.